# How to retrieve index of min value from specified column in array?

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm working on kmeans clustering algorithm, 
 and I need to find the index of the smallest value specified column in the array

For example, I wrote this code for 3 item to find min from column j:

```
if ((DistanceArray[1, j] < DistanceArray[2, j]) && 
    (DistanceArray[1, j] < DistanceArray[3, j]))
{
    min= 1;
} 
else if (DistanceArray[2, j] < DistanceArray[3, j])
{
    min= 2;
}
else
{
    min= 3;
}
```

But I need to retrieve minimum value from a multidimensional array.

How can do this?

Comment: You know that you can have more than one index for the min value. if this values appear in more than one place in you array.

Answer (score 0):

```
        float min = float.MaxValue;
        int minindex = 0;
        for (int t = 1; t <= k; t++)
        {
            if (DistanceArray[t, j]<=min)
            {
                min = DistanceArray[t, j];
                minindex = t;
            }
        }
        DatasetArray[0, j] = minindex;
```